# Transition not working after applying display: table

Tags: css, html, css-transitions

I have a `<table>` inside of a `<div>` and I wanted my `<div>` to scale accordingly to my `<table>`. This `<div>` will only appear when I clicked on a button. When appearing, there should be a sliding transition. However, the transition disappears after I added `display: table;` to my CSS.

```
input.toggle ~ div 
{ 
    transition: .6s all cubic-bezier(0.730, -0.485, 0.145, 1.620); 
}

input.toggle:checked ~ div 
{ 
    display: table;
}
```

The effect I am trying to apply is in this link: http://demosthenes.info/blog/506/HTML5-Window-Toggle-Events-In-Pure-CSS3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property

Comment: I don't understand what exactly should be transitioned. Besides, isn't the shorthand property of transition supposed to be `transition: property-name speed ease-mode, ...` ?

Comment: @JoshCrozier Thank you. However, the link you provided doesn't really helped me because the transition they are discussing on is opacity, where they can use visibility to solve the problem they had.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have added a property which is not animatable on the element which you are trying to transition.

This causes the transition to cease to work.

See [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transitions/#animatable-properties-) - that display is not one of the animatable-properties

So you have to remove the  `display: table;` rule from the `input.toggle:checked ~ div` class.

Stick to [the code](http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/tjzcm) as proposed in the article - it works fine.

Comment: As mentioned, I wanted my <div> to scale accordingly to the <table>. That's the reason I am using display:table property. Is there any other way to do this so I can apply the transition?